# Checking if number is within range not working in PHP?

Tags: php, math, if-statement

I'm using this code:

```
if (($height/$width) > 0.5 && ($height/$width) < 0.8) {
  // do stuff
}
```

For a particular image, `$height/$width` evaluates to `0.66543438077634` (1080/1623).  And yet this appears to be evaluating as false.  Can anyone suggest why?

Comment: Have you tried to parse float the height and width before the comparison? Somehing like: `if ((floatval($height)/floatval($width)) > 0.5) ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably You have some problem someware else because this code works fine:

```
<?
    $height = 1080;
    $width = 1623;
    if (($height/$width) > 0.5 && ($height/$width) < 0.8) {
        echo 'IT WORKS';
    }
    var_dump(($height/$width));
?>
```

[**SEE WORKING CODE!**](http://codepad.org/x4XzqhIw)

Comment: Yes, this was a different issue... Wasn't testing well enough.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like

```
$div = (float)($height/$width);
if ( $div > 0.5 && $div < 0.8) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or you can use

```
$div = (float)($height)/(float)($width);
```

Comment: No dice... Still false.